# Solrnet can't get mapping to work

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using VS2012, .NET 4.5 and SolrNet. I am struggling with solrnet mappings. I've succesfully started Apache Solr with jetty on `http://localhost:8983/solr`. My class which I want to add to solr is:

```
public class Register
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("body")]  
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I succesfully connect to solr, but I can't put my document into it:

```
Startup.Init<Register>(solrAddress);
Solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Register>>();   

var reg = new Register
                    { 
                        Id = "SP2514N",                       
                        Body = @"Dosel je prosel"
                    };               

                Solr.Add(reg);
                Solr.Commit();
```

Here I receive error, that 'body' is unknown field. I've also used MappingManager, like this:

```
var mgr = new MappingManager();
            var property = typeof(Register).GetProperty("Id");
            mgr.Add(property, "id");
            mgr.SetUniqueKey(property);
            mgr.Add(typeof(Register).GetProperty("Body"), "body");
```

But, again, my field was not mapped. What am I doing wrong? Isn't the mapping to solr supposed to be done through code? Do I need a special xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to confirm that you have a `body` field defined in your schema. If you are just using the default schema that comes with Solr, it does not include a `body` field. You can copy an existing similar entry in the schema.xml file, like `description` to get you going.

For more reference on configuring the Solr schema please refer to the following:

- [Solr Reference Guide - Overview of Documents, Fields and Schema Design](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Overview+of+Documents,+Fields,+and+Schema+Design)
- [schema.xml - SolrTutorial.com](http://www.solrtutorial.com/schema-xml.html)

Comment: I've added field in schema.xml and it works! Later I had the problem with not existing 'waitFlush' parameter, but luckily that was well known issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/solrnet/gs1GrqSF9Zs